# Activity back navigation

Tags: android

If I have activities like following path,

```
A --> B --> C --> D
```

Currently I am in Activity D. So If I want to go back directly to B, then how it is possible?

I done the following way.

```
List<Activity> activities = new ArrayList<>();
```

This list will have the all loaded activities, which means activities added to this list on `onCreate()` method.

So currently this list will have `A, B, C, D`, So if want to go back directly to `B` then what I will do is get the last two activities from this list and finish it by using `finish()`. I know this is not the proper way.

So I want to know, whether there is any better way to do this or not?.

> Note : At some cases only I will go to Activity B directly, So I can't
>   finish C while start Activity D.

**Update**

Also I can go back to Activity A directly from Activity D, So my question is

> I can skip any activity at any time and also go back to any
>   activity at any time

is it possible?

Comment: while going from C to D, just finish the C Activity. When u press back then it will directly go to the B Activity

Comment: @DemoMail I have added note, please take a look on it.

Comment: In that cases you can explicitly call that activity again via intent on back press

Comment: @VivekMishra No Vivek, its wrong, then this same activity will be two time at stack.

Comment: finish that activity before as stated above

Comment: means always finish activity c and the case when you want activity c then call it again via intent

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use startActivityForResult when starting Activity D from Activity C.

Whenever you want to finish Activity C, make sure you do setResult(RESULT_OK) in Activity D when you're about to finish it.

And in Activity C, override onActivityResult and do the following:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SHOULD_FINISH_ACTIVITY) {
        //add any other code you might wanna add
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, Added +1, But what if I go directly to Activity A. So my question is I can negotiate any activity at any time and also go back to any activity at any time.

Comment: Well you can either do the same thing for Activity A, or even though I'm not a fan of this, you can make your own activity stack just like what you did. But instead of inserting every activity in onCreate, you should make your own Application file and do registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks() in its onCreate. Manipulate your activity stack there instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use IntentFlag to clear all previous activty.
you must read this tutorials for more clearfication.

[Main Reference : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

[Source : http://tips.androidhive.info/2013/10/how-to-clear-all-activity-stack-in-android/](http://tips.androidhive.info/2013/10/how-to-clear-all-activity-stack-in-android/)

```
 Intent i = new Intent(D.this, B.class);
// set the new task and clear flags
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can implement separate OnBackPressed() Method for each activity and move to any activity you want, but if you want to save the instance of the current activity also you need to use StartActivityForResult() method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onBackPressed method on your D Actvity like this.

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
Intent i = new Intent(D.this, B.class);
startActivity(i);
    }
```